# Entity Framework adding List object to Repository.EFModel

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two sets of data: customercurrentGroupSubscriptions where I want to add to a EF select statement. The customercurrentGroupSubscriptions  is a list and I am trying to use that data in the EFModel select but getting this error about `edm type is ambiguous` do I need to do anything different for this to work?

Error

```
Schema specified is not valid clr types
```

Code

```
     var customercurrentGroupSubscriptions = customergroupSubscriptions.GroupBy(r => r.GroupId)
         .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.EndDate.Value).FirstOrDefault())
         .Select(i => new CustomerGroupSubscriptions
            {
                SubscriptionId = i.SubscriptionId,
                GroupId = i.GroupId,
                EndDate = i.EndDate
            }).ToList();

     var SubscriptionsForGroupSubscription = (from s in db.Subscriptions
        join i in customercurrentGroupSubscriptions on s.SubscriptionId equals i.SubscriptionId
          select new IndividualGroupSubscription
                 {
                     OriginalSubscriptionId = s.OriginalSubscriptionId
                 }
      ).toList();
```

Comment: EF tries to translate the query into SQL. There's no SQL translation for an in-memory list of objects. Since you only need a match on `SubscriptionId` use `.Select(i => i.SubscriptionId`) and use this collection in a `Contains` statement.

Comment: Do I need to take out the join for customercurrentGroupSubscriptions ?